# Throw an exception within a ContinueWith block

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm calling a web service asynchronously using HttpClient and am handling the response using `ContinueWith`. Within this, I want to check the `HttpStatusCode` and throw an exception if it's not 200 (success).

My code is as follows:

```
// Call the GetAddress service passing in the postcode
var task = client.GetAsync(url)
    .ContinueWith((taskWithResponse) =>
    {                    
        var response = taskWithResponse.Result;
        ValidateResponse(response.StatusCode);
        var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        jsonString.Wait();
         model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetAddressResults>(jsonString.Result);
            });
task.Wait();

private static void ValidateResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
{
    Exception exception = null;
    switch(statusCode)
    {
        case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            exception = new NotFoundException();
            break;
        case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
            exception = new InvalidException();
            break;
        case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
            exception = new ForbiddenException();
            break;
        case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)429:
            exception = new ExceededLimitException();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    throw exception;
}
```

However when running this instead of returning one of the exceptions I've specified it's instead caught by `task.Wait()` which throws and `AggregateException`.

Is there a way of getting the task to throw the exception that I initially wanted or do I need to put a try/catch round the `Wait()` method and pull my exception type out?

Comment: *I'm calling a web service asynchronously*. Nope, you're using `task.Wait()`, you're *synchronously blocking*. Any reason you're not using async-await?

Comment: The AggregateException will contain any exceptions thrown in it's InnerExceptions property

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, there's one dramatic thing about this code - the `ValidateResponse` method. This `switch` statement is terrible - read about factories, they are the pattern used to handle this kind of situations.

Comment: You are trying to innovate [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and its not that easy as you can see. Way easier is to make extension method with delegate, e, g: `client.Validate(o => o.Get()).DoSomething()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the web service *synchronously*. Use `await` / `async` keywords instead:

```
try 
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    ValidateResponse(response.StatusCode);
    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetAddressResults>(jsonString);
} 
catch (NotFoundException e) 
{
    // ...
}
catch (ForbiddenException e) 
{
    // ...
}
...
```

If you cannot use those keywords (Maybe in Visual Studio 2010), just catch `AggregateException` and check it's `InnerExceptions` property.